# MTB Shimano MT610 crankset with 32t: possible switch to 30t?

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, chainring

I'm looking at the [Raven 8.7](https://www.focusitaliagroup.it/it/focus/mountain-raven/raven/raven-8-7-barolo-red-di/2020/) with its Shimano MT610 crankset with 32 teeth. The bike comes equipped with Shimano SLX M7100, 12-speed cassette and Shimano Deore XT M8100, 12-speed rear derailleur. I would need a more favourable ratio for the climbs so I'm trying to make sure the original 32t chainring can be swapped with the 30t version.
Here's the manufacturer's page (https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/slx-m7100/FC-MT610.html).

How can I be sure I'll be able to swap the 32t chainring with a 30t one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can swap for a 30T chainring. The Shimano page (link you provided) states that the crank arm is compatible with a 30T ring, and they provide a [link](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/service-upgradeparts/shimano/Y0K430000.html) with a part number (Y0K430000) to the exact Shimano chainring that would replace your 32T.

Comment: Shimano manuals state cross-compatibility between XT and SLX components. Source: https://si.shimano.com/#/en/DM/MAFC002